# Solving equation in Python 3.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.3

So to figure out the day of the week from any date since 15 of october you can use a simple piece of arithmetic my problem is that i have read from a file the date (for e.g. 2009-06-12) and i have put the equation in:

```
w = (d + [2.6 * m - 0.2] + Y + [Y / 4] + 5 * C + [C / 4] ) % 7
```

The dates are in the format yyyy-mm-dd and my code looks like this:

```
count = 5
f = open('/Users/student/Desktop/Harry.txt').readlines()[count]
Y = f[2:4]
C = f[:2]
m = f[5:7]
d = f[8:10]
w = (d + [2.6 * m - 0.2] + Y + [Y / 4] + 5 * C + [C / 4] ) % 7
if w == 0:
    print (f, "is a Sunday")
elif w == 1:
    print (f, "is a Monday")
elif w == 2:
    print (f, "is a Tuesday")
elif w == 3:
    print (f, "is a Wednesday")
elif w == 4:
    print (f, "is a Thursday")
elif w == 5:
    print (f, "is a Friday")
elif w == 6:
    print (f, "is a Saturday")
```

to clarify:

```
w = day of the week counting from Sunday = 0 Monday = 1
d = the day of the month (for e.g. 28th 13th)
m = month number where March = 1 etc.
Y = last 2 digits of year
C = first 2 digits of year
```

Yet i get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/student/Documents/workspace/Tutorial Challenges/src/Day_Of_The_Week.py", line 7, in <module>
    w = (d + [2.6 * m - 0.2] + Y + [Y / 4] + 5 * C + [C / 4] ) % 7
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Y`, `C`, `m`, and `d` are all strings. You want to convert them into ints first:

```
Y = int(f[2:4])
C = int(f[:2])
...
```

Are you sure that equation even works, though? It looks like it'd produce a lot of non-integer weekdays. You might've miscopied it. Also, brackets aren't a grouping operator in Python; they're the list construction syntax. You'll want to replace those brackets with parentheses in the expression for `w`. (Or were those brackets supposed to be the floor operator? If so, you'll want `math.floor`, from the `math` module, or just `int` if truncation is fine.)

Comment: ive tryed that yet it doesnt let as i cant change 'list' to 'int'

Comment: Sorry no that now works after adding int to Y, C etc and adding () instead of []

Answer (score 0):

As the above user has said, you want to convert from string to int. However, this is the ideal place to use the datetime module. You can use this to specify that your datetime is of the format: yyyy-mm-dd, and use the module to load up the info as datetime.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

Comment: thats a great idea but in this task it specifys im not allowed to use the datetime module

Comment: Ohh, ok. Could you add some sample lines from Harry.txt to your question? That would help clarify what you are reading in.